# What Is The Best Way To Clone A Database From Production To Development Environment?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

We use SQL Server at our company as DBMS. I have a scheduled job working monthly. The job restores every databases on production server to development server at the end of the month but there is insufficient disk issue on the development server. I truncate some big tables which are not important for development teams and shrink all databases after the restore completed. Shrinking databases takes too long time to increase free disk space on development server. Of course, this is not good solution. I need a better or the best solution for the situation. I need your advices. How can i use more efficient method? What would be the best solution?

Comment: i mean which version 2017 2019 or are you using all versions you tagged

Comment: In fact, we use all versions that i tagged. But, i don't care 2016 and older versions. The servers that i am concerned in have SQL Server 2017 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Omer, It sounds like you are saying that you don't have enough space on the Dev server to restore all of the databases from prod without truncating some tables and shrinking the database to recover space. I'm unsure if you mean above that increasing the size of the drives on the Dev server is an option or not. That part is unclear.

I would push to increase the size of the drives and explaining to your storage team or Windows Admins that you need the space in order to avoid doing the damaging shrink operation as part of your restore process.

Comment: Lee, thank you very much for your answer. You got me correct. Yeah, I mean i don't have enough space on dev server to restore all databases from prod. So, i do that operation. I talked to system administrator to add more disk to the dev server but he did not accept my request because of disk bottleneck. What should i do now i don't know. I have to bring a solution to this situation

Comment: Omer -  First, examine whether these databases on production could have any of their data archived in a read-only filegroup or if there is simply old data being kept for no good reason. If you can archive data into a different read-only filegroup, then you can restore just the read-write filegroups to dev. That may save you some space. Second, if you have Enterprise Edition, consider compression for space savings. Third, consider explaining to the SysAdmins how not having the disk space is negatively impacting the Development efforts.to persuade them to give the server the space.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be shrinking your databases, it's an expensive and unnecessary operation. Truncating the tables is fine and at that point you've freed up some of your used space internally. So if more data is added in that database after you truncated, it'll reuse that freed up space first instead of taking more space from the drive.

If you want a tool that's a more manual process of keeping the databases across servers in sync, I've found the [SQL Examiner Suite](https://www.sqlaccessories.com/) simple and excellent of a tool to do so.

If you want something more automated, you should look into one-direction replication. You can use [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) for near real-time synchronization between your Production and Development server or if you want to continue to only update it at fixed internals (e.g. Monthly) you can use [Snapshot Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-replication?view=sql-server-ver15).

With either solution, you can choose more granularly which Tables you want to keep synchronized in your Development environment, so this will eliminate your space issue and the need to run heavy operations like Shrink.